# Is there a an option for turning on compression for D2C telemetry data sent to the Azure IoT Hub?

Tags: azure, compression, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, telemetry

I am using the Azure IoT Device SDK for JavaScript and I cannot find in the documentation
[Azure IoT Device Package API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-iot-device/?view=azure-node-latest) any references to turning on compression for data sent to the cloud.  I am wondering if I am missing something or if the data is automatically being compressed.

Comment: why dont you try libraries like pako.js for explicit compression?

Comment: Ghandi, ultimately we may end up using a library on both the client side and server sides to compress/decompress.  I just thought Microsoft Azure might have this built in as an option, especially if you are using their JavaScript SDK.

Comment: Ghandi, I did end up using pako.js for some to compress some files that are being ingested.

Comment: can i post the answer so that u can approve it for other's benefit?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t find any option for turning on compression for D2C data sent to Azure IoT Hub.

But You can follow below path for compression of D2C telemetry data sent to the Azure IoT Hub.

A Node.js script reads telemetry data from sensors, compresses that data with Avro and then sends to IoT Hub.

IoT Hub itself “supports compression” because it doesn’t crack the message payload - it just treats the message as bytes across the wire. So, the cloud endpoint (IoT Hub) isn’t an issue. The issue arises when we need to use compression and then process those messages post-ingestion. Azure Stream Analytics, a common Azure IoT message ingestor, supports JSON, CSV and Avro.

For more details you can follow this [article](https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/05/azure-iot-stream-analytics-avro-nodejs/)